# Is this relative homology equals to wedge sum of two tori?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

If $X$ is a connected sum of tow tori, and $A$ is its center circle as shown in picture below.

[image]

I would like to compute $H_n(X,A)$. There is a statement in the book that $H_n(X,A)$ represents the homology of the quotient space $X/A$ obtained by collapsing $A$ to a point.

If I do that, then I got wedge sum of two tori $T\vee T$

[image]

So $H_n(X,A)=H_n(T\vee T)$
$$H_0(X,A)=\mathbb{Z}$$
$$H_1(X,A)=\mathbb{Z}^4$$
$$H_2(X,A)=\mathbb{Z}^2$$
$$H_n(X,A)=0, n\geq 3$$

But why the solution for $n=2$ gives $H_2(X,A)=\mathbb{Z}$?

Is the solution wrong or I am mistaken something here?

Comment: what is $p$??///

Comment: @Anubhav.K sorry typo, should be $n$

Comment: I didnt get your question at all

Comment: @Anubhav.K, he's asking whether his calculations are correct.

Comment: It seems to be correct

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly an error of the statement. In fact, since $A\subset X$ is a sub complex, then it is indeed true that $$ H_n(X,A)\cong \widetilde{H}_n(X/A)$$ (one can even take it to be the definition of the first object) Now apply the wedge axiom for a reduced homology theory to obtain that the reduced homology group of a wedge sum of spaces is the direct sum of the reduced homology groups of the spaces, in formula $$\widetilde{H}_n(\bigvee_n X_n)\cong \bigoplus_n\widetilde{H}_n(X_n)$$

An advice: even though in this singular homology setting, homology and reduced homology doesn't differ much (only in degree $0$ by a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$) I suggest to take care of wether we are working with one theory or the other. This will come in handy when dealing with  generalised homology theories where the difference is more "interesting".